# NullPointerException on setContentView

Tags: android

I am having two layouts in same `xml` file and I have kept one layout as hidden and want to show this hidden layout on `button` click. But when I try to load this `activity`, it gives me exception on `setContentView`. 
Here is my layout:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#f0f5f9"
            tools:context="com.techsof.demoapp.Auftrag">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/heading"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/heading_text"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/form_heading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/header"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/form_heading"
                android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/form"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/form_heading"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_fields"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:hint="@string/name"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/mail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_fields"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:hint="@string/mail_"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_fields"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:hint="Tel/Mobilnummer *"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/aus"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_fields"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:hint="Ausgangssprache *"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ziel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_fields"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:hint="Zielsprache *"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/nach"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_fields"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:hint="Nachricht *"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/doc1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/odd_corners"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:padding="10dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/attach_btn1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/odd_corners_btn"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
                        android:text="@string/doc1"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/doc2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/odd_corners"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:padding="10dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/attach_btn2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/odd_corners_btn"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
                        android:text="@string/doc2"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/doc3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/odd_corners"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:padding="10dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/attach_btn3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/odd_corners_btn"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
                        android:text="@string/doc3"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footer_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/form"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/footer_text"
                android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/footer_text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:buttonTint="#0F84AA"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="@string/checkbox_text"
                android:textColor="#4c4c4c"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/checkbox"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
                android:text="@string/button_text"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialogBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4c4c4c"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/complete_action_using"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cameraOption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#CDCDCD"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/camera"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/phoneStorageOption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#CDCDCD"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_open_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/phone_storage"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#CDCDCD"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#0F84AA"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#f0f5f9"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="#000"
        app:itemTextColor="#000"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and here is my Java Code:

```
public class Auftrag extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout eDrawerlayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle eToggle;
    NavigationView nav;
    private LinearLayout camera, phone, dialog;
    private Button attachBtn1, attachBtn2, attachBtn3, submitButton, cancel;
    private TextView file1, file2, file3;
    private EditText name, mail, telephone, ausgang, ziels, nachricht;
    private ArrayList<Uri> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
    private CheckBox agreement;
    private String textfield;

    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        initUI();

        eToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, eDrawerlayout, R.string.Open, R.string.Close);
        eDrawerlayout.addDrawerListener(eToggle);
        eToggle.syncState();
        nav.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#f0f5f9")));
        eDrawerlayout.setDrawerListener(eToggle);

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    }

    private void initUI() {
        nav = findViewById(R.id.navigation1);
        eDrawerlayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer1);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        mail = findViewById(R.id.mail);
        telephone = findViewById(R.id.tel);
        ausgang = findViewById(R.id.aus);
        ziels = findViewById(R.id.ziel);
        nachricht = findViewById(R.id.nach);
        submitButton = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        attachBtn1 = findViewById(R.id.attach_btn1);
        attachBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.attach_btn2);
        attachBtn3 = findViewById(R.id.attach_btn3);
        /*dialog = findViewById(R.id.dialogBox);
        camera = findViewById(R.id.cameraOption);
        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openCamera();
            }
        });
        phone = findViewById(R.id.phoneStorageOption);
        phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });
        cancel = findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });*/
        file1 = findViewById(R.id.doc1);
        file2 = findViewById(R.id.doc2);
        file3 = findViewById(R.id.doc3);
        attachBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textfield = "btn1";
                chooseOption();
                /*dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/
            }
        });
        attachBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textfield = "btn2";
                /*dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/
            }
        });
        attachBtn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textfield = "btn3";
                /*dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/
            }
        });
        agreement = findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendData();
            }
        });

    }


    private void chooseOption() {

        final CharSequence[] options = {"Camera", "Phone", "Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Add file using: ");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Camera")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Phone")) {
                    openFileChooser();
                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
    }

    private void sendData() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(mail.getText()) ||
                TextUtils.isEmpty(telephone.getText()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(ausgang.getText())
                || TextUtils.isEmpty(ziels.getText()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(nachricht.getText())
                || TextUtils.isEmpty(file1.getText()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(file3.getText()) ||
                TextUtils.isEmpty(file3.getText())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (agreement.isChecked()) {
                if (isConnected()) {
                    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
                    data.add(name.getText().toString());
                    data.add(mail.getText().toString());
                    data.add(telephone.getText().toString());
                    data.add(ausgang.getText().toString());
                    data.add(ziels.getText().toString());
                    data.add(nachricht.getText().toString());
                    new SendMailTask(this).execute("metaphrase.online@gmail.com", "Admintogether-2000222",
                            "salman.footy.k7@gmail.com", "User Information", data.get(0), data.get(1),
                            data.get(2), data.get(3), data.get(4), data.get(5), getFullPath(attachments.get(0)),
                            getFullPath(attachments.get(1)), getFullPath(attachments.get(2)));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your internet connection and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please select the checkbox.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (eToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {

        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();


        switch (id) {
            case R.id.home:
                startActivity(new Intent(Auftrag.this, MainActivity.class));

                break;

            case R.id.web:
                Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://metaphrase.online"));
                startActivity(browser);
                break;

            case R.id.help:
                startActivity(new Intent(Auftrag.this, Feedback.class));
                break;
            case R.id.upload:
                if (isConnected()) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(Auftrag.this, Auftrag.class));


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Internetverbindung!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;


        }
        eDrawerlayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode != REQUEST_SELECT_FILE || resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No file selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            importFile(intent);
        }
    }

    private void importFile(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            String fileName = getFileName(intent.getData());
            if (textfield != null) {
                if (textfield.equals("btn1")) {
                    dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    file1.setText(fileName);
                    attachments.add(intent.getData());
                } else if (textfield.equals("btn2")) {
                    dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    file2.setText(fileName);
                    attachments.add(intent.getData());
                } else {
                    dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    file3.setText(fileName);
                    attachments.add(intent.getData());
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    }

    private String getFullPath(Uri fileUri) {
        String filePath = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            try {
                filePath = PathUtil.getPath(this, fileUri);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
            final String[] split = file.getPath().split(":");
            filePath = split[1];
        }
        return filePath;
    }

    private String getFileName(Uri data) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(data, null, null, null, null);


        if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            cursor.close();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't obtain file name, cursor is empty");
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));

        cursor.close();

        return fileName;
    }


    public boolean isConnected() {
        boolean connected = false;
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo nInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            connected = nInfo != null && nInfo.isAvailable() && nInfo.isConnected();
            return connected;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Connectivity Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connected;
    }


}
```

Comment: Post your Activity Java or Kotlin code...

Comment: @dmak2709 posted. Please check.

Comment: The whole class please because I would like to test it in my Android Studio

Comment: @dmak2709 maximum number of characters exceeded here if I put whole class.

Comment: Maybe delete the logcat or at least some lines because you have like a million variables...

Comment: @dmak2709 done. Had to delete the import lines. Please add them from your studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPE while inflating layout (Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259335/npe-while-inflating-layout-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-boolean-java-lang)

Comment: Try to change all the `<view ... />` tags in `<View ... />`

Comment: @dmak2709 argh...works fine after changing <view.../> tag to <View.../> 
How can I not think about that at first place? Thank you so much for pointing that out brother. Life Saviour. :)

Comment: @dmak2709 just a quick question. As you can see that there are edittext in the layout and when I show my hidden layout on top of those fields, I can still click on those backgroung fields and write something into them. I want to lock those edittext fields from typing when my hidden layout is visible on the screen.

Comment: Which layout? The id?

Comment: @dmak2709 dialogBox. When this layout is visible on the screen, I want all the edittexts on the background of this layout to be non-editable.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862947/disable-all-edittext-inside-linear-layout

Comment: I suggest you to create a custom dialog....

Comment: @dmak2709 Thanks !!

Comment: @dmak2709 have you worked with Javamail library to send message with attachments?

Comment: No I didn't. Hahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem should be in the `<view ../>` tag, the correct form is `<View ... />`. You should change your XML file with the following:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#f0f5f9"
            tools:context="com.techsof.demoapp.Auftrag">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/heading"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/heading_text"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/form_heading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/header"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/form_heading"
                android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/form"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/form_heading"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_fields"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:hint="@string/name"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/mail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_fields"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:hint="@string/mail_"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_fields"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:hint="Tel/Mobilnummer *"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/aus"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_fields"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:hint="Ausgangssprache *"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ziel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_fields"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:hint="Zielsprache *"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/nach"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_fields"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:hint="Nachricht *"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/doc1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/odd_corners"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:padding="10dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/attach_btn1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/odd_corners_btn"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
                        android:text="@string/doc1"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/doc2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/odd_corners"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:padding="10dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/attach_btn2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/odd_corners_btn"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
                        android:text="@string/doc2"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/doc3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/odd_corners"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:padding="10dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/attach_btn3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/odd_corners_btn"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
                        android:text="@string/doc3"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footer_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/form"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/footer_text"
                android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/footer_text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:buttonTint="#0F84AA"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="@string/checkbox_text"
                android:textColor="#4c4c4c"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/checkbox"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
                android:text="@string/button_text"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialogBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4c4c4c"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/complete_action_using"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cameraOption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#CDCDCD"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/camera"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/phoneStorageOption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#CDCDCD"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_open_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/phone_storage"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#CDCDCD"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#0F84AA"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#f0f5f9"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="#000"
        app:itemTextColor="#000"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```