# enable and disable TextView's editable mode

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

I'm creating an spread sheet app. I use a lot of textView in a table layout as the cells of the spread sheet. I want as the user double tap on a cell(TextView), the cell become editable (just like an editText). also, I need to disable the cell's edit mode after the user tap on another cell. I tried these methods but nothing happened.

```
    private void enableEditMode(TextView cell) {
       cell.setFocusable(true);
       cell.setEnabled(true);
       cell.setClickable(true);
       cell.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
       cell.setCursorVisible(true);
    }

    private void disableEditMode(TextView cell) {
       cell.setFocusable(false);
       cell.setEnabled(false);
       cell.setClickable(false);
       cell.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
       cell.setCursorVisible(false);
    }
```

Comment: Does this works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862947/disable-all-edittext-inside-linear-layout?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to make EditText uneditable.

```
private void enableEditMode(EditText cell) {
       cell.setFocusable(true);
    }

    private void disableEditMode(EditText cell) {
       cell.setFocusable(false);
    }
```

should work